# Appium: isDisplayed() vs findElements(by).size

Tags: java, iphone, testing, automation, appium

Traditionally I always checked for the presence of objects in appium using:

```
    int count = driver.findElements(by).size();
            if (count == 0) {
        Logger.LogMessage("ElementDoesNotExist: " + by, Priority.Medium);
        return true;
    } else {
        Logger.LogMessage("ElementDoesExist: " + by, Priority.Medium);
        return false;
    }
```

However, I see there is now a isDisplayed() method:

```
    driver.findElement(by).isDisplayed()
```

Anyone know which is best to use and why?

Thanks,

Charlie

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is mostly Selenium question. When you use findElements you are looking for the **presence** element in DOM. However the element presence still not ensure that the element will **visible**. In order to verify the element **display** state you have to use isDisplayed method. For example in case the large page not all elements existing in the page DOM will be displayed.

Please see the details in W3C WebDriver [specification](https://w3c.github.io/webdriver/webdriver-spec.html)

Comment: Thanks Eugene.  So in effect: isDisplayed() shows if the element is visible to the user Vs findElements which show the element is on the page (visible or not).  Do you know if isDisplayed() also works for appium (i.e. whether an object is actually visible on the iphone screen or not)?

Comment: AFAIK this is the same for appium.

Comment: This doesnt seem to be the case in appium :-(.  Just checked for isDisplayed for the bottom UITableViewCell when viewing the top of the UITableView and it came back as true..