# Selenium failed result to equal a passed test

Tags: selenium

I am creating test case to confirm that certain fields are required. Upon submitting my form a "Success" banner should NOT display if all the required fields aren't filled out. So here is my code snippet to see if the banner is shown on the page...

```
checkRequestConfirm = webDriver.FindElement(By.ClassName("apx-success-message")).Displayed;
```

This obviously fails the test because the banner isn't there. But that's what I want. I want this to pass because the banner didn't show. Any suggestions are greatly appreciated! I know I may be approaching this incorrectly and am open to improvements.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean to check if the banner exists, I'd wait until some other element is loaded (just to make sure the test isn't run before the banner shows), and then use:

```
checkRequestConfirm = webDriver.findElements(By.ClassName("apx-success-message")).size() == 0
```

If you want to check if it's visible, just use:

```
checkRequestConfirm = !webDriver.FindElement(By.ClassName("apx-success-message")).isDisplayed()
```

You can read further about the differences between the methods [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30621713/appium-isdisplayed-vs-findelementsby-size).

Comment: the isDisplayed() method doesn't come up for me. Is that an extension of selenium?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the framework you are using. You didn't specify a language but I'm guessing C#? For C# there is NUnit or if you are using Java there is JUnit, TestNG, etc. All of these frameworks (and others) have the concept of passing a test if a boolean is false.

For NUnit the syntax would be something like

```
Assert.False(webDriver.FindElement(By.ClassName("apx-success-message")).Displayed, "Success message is NOT present");
```

Read more about it here: https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/Assert.False

If you aren't using a framework, I highly suggest you find one for the language you are using.